# dompdf page breaking table if exceed table height

Tags: html, css, dompdf

i want to break my table in the middle, as you can see at the picture. i want to break the table, so the table will stop at 10 and continue number 11 at the next page. how should i do it?

this is my css.

```
table.item {
        width: 100%;
        height: 190px;
        page-break-after: always;
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }
```

and it's work, i just need to move the number after 10 to the next page / the table exceed the height.

if i use overflow : hidden;

it sure to hide the row but not showing at the next page. any 1 have idea?

[image]

thanks for your time sire. best regards

Comment: Need to see a bit more of your code. On which element is the "item" class applied?

Comment: @BrianS already solve.. thanks sire

Comment: @rudzstyle, can you please share the solution?